# What are "pushing horns"?

Tags: nouns, meaning-in-context

This is from a song by Garth Brooks called The Cowboy Song:

> Pushing horns weren't easy like the movie said it was
>   And I don't recall no dance hall girls
>   Or hotel rooms with rugs
>   You worked hot and tired and nasty
>   Rode your pony's head too low
>   There were all the nights you couldn't sleep
>   'Cause it was too damn cold
>   And you'd sing "Strawberry Roan" and "Little Joe"

Can anybody tell me what "pushing horns" refers to, and possibly the name of the movie in question as well?

Comment: *Pushing horns* means driving cattle.

Comment: The movie is probably just any generic Hollywood Western glamorization of the old West.

Comment: @StoneyB Yes. But more specifically, it refers to driving [Texas Longhorn](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texas_Longhorn) cattle.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if I can source this but pushing horns but my sense as a speaker of American English is that this means moving cattle around, i.e., being a cattle rancher.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, that must be it. @StoneyB also thinks the same.

Answer (score 1):

I believe virmaior and the various commenters are correct. This is referring to what a cowboy used to do on a cattle drive to move the herds around.

As a resident of the same metropolis as Mr. Brooks (Greater Tulsa, OK), and a person who has in fact worked cattle in the area, I can also say that I'd never heard that term for it before. Its not a common term we use for working cattle. I wouldn't be shocked if the author hadn't made it up himself.

Note that [cattle drives](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chisholm_Trail) mostly ended with the end of the open range around the beginning of the 20th Century. Today cattle herds are contained year round on their own ranches. They occasionally have to be rounded up for shots and er... creating steers from the new calfs, but they almost never need to be driven serious distances from horseback anymore. So this was probably written from the point of view of a person who would not be alive today.

Comment: Oh, and to take Mr. Brooks' effort at de-glamorization a bit further, I'd like to point out that rather a large proportion (probably the majority) of the cowboys on these drives would also have been either black or Indian. You don't see that in Hollywood movies either, or in a lot of neo-cowboy songs.

Comment: Mr Brooks didn't write the song. Roy Robinson of Comanche, TX did.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch - Interesting. So apparently its from a central Texan in the late 1980s. That may explain the (to me) weird lingo, I suppose. However, the phrase still somehow feels way too modern for someone on an actual cattle drive. It sounds much more like trucker lingo. I can at least vouch that we weren't using it for working cattle up in Tulsa at about the same time.

Comment: It was written in 1987, but it is an older breed of cattle. Obviously, a caballero didn't write the song.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch - Well now, I didn't spend much time in that exact part of Texas in the mid 80's, but I did pass through the panhandle a time or two, and they did in fact still have what looked to my non-FFA eyes to be longhorn cattle there. I don't ever remember seeing any in Oklahoma though. My Grandfather's herd was all Angus and Herford.

Comment: I only meant it is a heritage breed.

Comment: Thank you so much for all this info. Being a native Spanish speaker born and raised in Europe, I obviously didn't have a clue.

Comment: @T.E.D. What looked to your "non-FFA eyes"... does FFA mean "Future Farmers of America"? I took horticulture classes in high school (it was mandatory for vocational ed requirements), and placed in entomology contests at the college, but never qualified for one of the blue, wide-waled corderoy FFA jackets with my county in yellow on the back. I still want one, even now.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps an otherwise alternative, calves (thru year-lings) are literally growing out "hornbuds" emitting from their skulls. An equiv. might also be a "Greenhorn." 
That would give the writer a ponderance of his/her youth.